# Sitecore skip custom pipelines based on HttpRequest

Tags: sitecore

I wanted to skip the execution of Sitecore pipelines based on (HttpCookie/Query string/header token). Is that possible?

I dont want to write something shown below in each of my custom pipeline.

```
 public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
    if (request does not contains token)
            return;

     //logic
   }
```

(or) Can I mention the next Pipeline to execute that I can skip unnecessary code execution?

Just trying to get find out a best solution.
Thanks.

Comment: That's the correct way of doing it. You can try and optimise if the code is called in several places and use base classes, but there is no other cleaner solution.

Comment: @hammykam - i feel sitecore should provide an interface/property in the PipelineArgs to programmatically specify the next pipeline process to execute? That would save some processing time if we have lot of custom pipelines to execute.Obviously we have a args.abortPipeline() but that doesnt solve my problem to skip and resume from a different process.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kam mentioned, that is a perfectly valid way to achieve it. In the current implementation of Sitecore pipelines each step is decoupled from the next and only coupled via the order defined in the configuration.

Depending on the number of variables and routes through your pipelines you could achieve a similar forking concept by defining multiple pipelines each with the steps you require. Your logic in the initial step would then be to decide which pipeline to run.

The approach I'd decide on would depend on the variation of each run through a pipeline and how many steps I wanted to vary/skip. If you only ever want to skip e.g. one or two steps, your approach would be my choice. If the variation is based on lots of steps I'd consider defining separate pipelines for each.

Comment: Yeah.. I agree. I ended up splitting the pipelines and using the abort to skip the processes ! But I wish to extend the pipeline by defining conditions in the config. I am thinking of a custom conditional pipeline that would accept the process/processes as a parameter along with the conditions to evaluate. The custom conditional pipeline is kind of gateway to execute the processes. May not be a good solution but should work.